# To check type II in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table consider A with
Fields A1, A2 where A1 is the unique/primary key and A2 is type II field.
Now i need to find A1 and A2 where the A2 gets updated/changed.
Can anyone please help with a query for this?

Sample data

```
A1     A2   A3
emp1   1     2
emp2   1     3
emp3   1     4
emp3   2     4
```

I should be getting the output as

```
A1     A2   A3
emp3   1     4
emp3   2     4
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data with the results you are looking for?

Comment: @ Gordon: I have updated with an example

Comment: . . Can you rephrase the question to match the data?  The data has three columns, your question only mentions two, for instance.

Comment: My table has many columns with type II fields, i had just mentioned one

Comment: You have a type 2 table with no date fields to indicate when a change was made?  How do you use it then?

Comment: Yup i do have date field, but there are thousands of records added up in a single day. So its becoming difficult if i am only using date. I have to use date + some condition. That condition is only i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
<your table>.*
from
<your table>
inner join 
(select a1, count (a2) as a2recs, count(a3) as a3Recs from <your table> group by a1 having (count (a2) > 1 or count (a3) > 1)) a
on <your table>.a1 = a.a1.
```

The inner query gives you all the `A1s` that have multiple values in the either of the other 2 columns.  You join that back to the original table on `A1`.

Comment: I tried like this..But its not working correctly. Can you please have a look.                                                    select * from TABLEA
inner join 
(select a1, count (a2) as a2recs  from TABLEA group by a1 having (count (a2) > 1 ) a
on TABLEA.a1 = a.a1.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may need to investigate a windowed aggregate function. The following may send you down the correct path:

```
SELECT A1
     , A2
     , MAX(A3) OVER(PARTITION BY A1, A2)
  FROM {MyDB}.{MyTable};
```